# pickerview in tableview cell doesn't work

Tags: swift, uitableview, uipickerview

When I try to use a pickerview to select tip amount, I have to relay that information to the view controller to be used by another tableview cell. When I reload the tableview, it reconfigures the pickerview in the cell, setting the tip to 0 when another amount was chosen. if I make it so the pickerview is only configured once by a bool statement that is true only the first time it configures, the pickerview freezes after the first selection, making a second adjustment impossible. When I tried to set the "selectRow" function to be the selected row and to reconfigure on the selected row, it doesn't work with the top and bottom fields writing over each other and the ability to update the tip stops working. I have no idea what other options there are for getting it work. Seems like this shouldn't be so difficult. Here's some code:

```
private func configurePickerView() {
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    pickerView.selectRow(selectedRow, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
    contentView.addSubview(pickerView)
    pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    pickerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.25).isActive = true
    guard let orderView = orderView else { return }
    pickerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orderView.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    pickerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orderView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    //let height = getSize(large: 45, medium: 45, small: 45)
    pickerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return tipArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return tipArray[row]
}
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selectedRow = row
    let tipAsInt = switchStatement(row)
    delegate?.reloadData(tipAsInt)
}

private func switchStatement(_ row: Int) -> Int {
    switch row {
    case 0: return Int(round(0 * Double(subTotal)))
    case 1: return Int(round(0.05 * Double(subTotal)))
    case 2: return Int(round(0.1 * Double(subTotal)))
    case 3: return Int(round(0.15 * Double(subTotal)))
    case 4: return Int(round(0.2 * Double(subTotal)))
    default: return Int(round(0.25 * Double(subTotal)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make

```
let pickerView = UIPickerView()
```

and instance var , so it's delegate and dataSource are retained

Also you should call

```
func configurePickerView() { // call it inside awakeFromNib or init
```

once as not to add multiple pickers to the tableCell and when you need a refresh call

```
pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Comment: the picker delegate and datasource refers to the cell which is retained , but i'm speaking about the item itself here it's pickerView as it's a local variable , plus the op needs a reference to it for upcoming refresh

Comment: Sh_Khan is right. I needed to make it an instance variable, declaring it outside the configurePickerView function. It works perfectly reconfiguring it each time now, without needing to call pickerView.reloadAllComponents(), though that may be best practice.